# Lifetime with shared state

Tags: rust, lifetime

I want to have:

- an `AppState` that has an `AppServices`,
- this `AppServices`  should have services `IdService`,
- `IdService` itself should have access to the `AppState`.

Below is the idea I came up with, but I am not able to get the lifetime markers done correctly.

```
struct IdService<'a> {
    name: String,
    state: &'a AppState,
}
struct AppServices<'a> {
    id: Option<&'a IdService>,
}

struct AppState<'a> {
    services: &'a AppServices,
}

impl<'a> AppState<'a> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        AppState {
            services: AppServices { id: None },
        };
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut state = AppState::new();
    let id_service = IdService {
        name: "test".to_string(),
        state: state,
    };
    let services = AppServices {
        id: Some(id_service),
    };
    state.services = services;
}
```

Compiler output:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:3:16
  |
3 |     state: &'a AppState,
  |                ^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter

error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
 --> src/main.rs:6:20
  |
6 |     id: Option<&'a IdService>,
  |                    ^^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter

error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:10:19
   |
10 |     services: &'a AppServices,
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected lifetime parameter
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your first struct has a reference that has a reference of another struct in itself, you need to specify these children lifetimes too:

```
struct AppState<'a> {
    services: &'a AppServices<'a>,
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e03f5c1c5443b9b6dec8546547448e8f)

This way you are saying to the compiler that `AppState` and `AppServices` lifetimes are bound, thus `AppServices` members have the lifetime `'a` as well.

However, apart from lifetime issues, you have a cyclic data structure. If you want to share data between structs, there are some specific smart pointers like [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) and for multithreaded applications [`Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html).

Instead of sharing raw pointers of the struct, you can share `Arc` smart pointers and mutate data with the help of `Mutex` to guarantee single access for a thread.

[A solution that uses an `Arc`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=5433755c30b18063724ed95e70e7a27a)
 to solve such a cyclic data structure problem.

Comment: Apart from `Rc` & `Arc`, there's also `Weak`. You can find more info in the [Creating Reference Cycles and Leaking Memory is Safe](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-06-reference-cycles.html) chapter in the Rust Programming Language Book.